# SOAP exception : axis2ns2:selectionFailure

Tags: exception, soap, soapexception

im getting an unknown exception when doing a request to a webservice:

```
axis2ns2:selectionFailure
```

Anyone know what the problem is ?

Edit: detailed error:

```
{"Message":"axis2ns5:selectionFailure","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)\r\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when there is an error with the xml namespace.